# How to extract values of sublists that have specific values in R

Tags: r, list, extract, sublist

I have a list that contains sublists ("double" objects) with headers. I want to extrat the values from one of those headers.

The image is the list:
[List with sublist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSsG6.png)

But this is what is looks like:

```
df                                         list(3)
     [1]   result.1                        double(2)
           Number_cluster 2                double(1)
           Value_index 3                   double(1)
     [2]   result.2                        double(2) 
           Number_cluster 6                double(1)
           Value_index 1                   double(1)
     [3]   result.3                        double(2) 
           Number_cluster 5                double(1)
           Value_index 6                   double(1)
```

The value to be extracted is "Number_clusters"

If I could extract these values from my data.frame, it would be usefull also

Data.frame:

```
[v1]        [v2]                                [v3]
c(1,2,3)    c(Number_clusters = 1, index= 2)
c(1,2,3)    c(Number_clusters = 7, index= 7.4)
```

I have tried

```
unique(rapply(b, function(x) head(b, )))
```

But this only gives me the values, both "Number_clusters" and "Index", but index is not usefull for me

dput output:

```
 list(result.1 = c(Number_clusters = 2, Value_Index = 7.0754), 
 result.2 = c(Number_clusters = 5, Value_Index = 7.142), result.3 = c(Number_clusters = 6, Value_Index = 11.235))
```

Comment: Please share sample data with `dput`

Comment: If your list is called `lst`, does this give you what you want? `sapply(lst, \`[[\`, 'Number_clusters')`?

Comment: It does! I can nest sapply if I want a sublist, for example:              `sapply(sapply(results, `[[`, 'Best.nc'), `[[`, 'Number_clusters')`